# Unequal size dual channel ram, and lower-than-expected frequency

Tags: memory, dell-inspiron, ddr3, dual-channel, cpu-z

I'm updating a Dell Inspiron N5030, and stumbled upon an odd situation. The laptop has 1 GB and 2 GB of DDR3 ram installed for a total of 3 GB, **Dual Channel**.

This is reported by both CPU-Z ("DC mode: Symmetric", even) and the machine's BIOS. How is this possible? Have I completely misunderstood what Dual Channel is?

PS: There is a further oddity, that both Dell specs and the BIOS claim that the ram is operating on 1333 MHz (MT/s, I suppose), but CPU-Z states that the mem clock divisor is 1:2, giving a 400 MHz clock and 800 MT/s. Given that the 2GB DIMM also only intermittently reports SPD data, might this be a case of needing a blast of compressed air? I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: The compressed air... it does nothing...
What is most confounding for me still is the lack of SPD for whatever is installed in socket 2. Especially as at least once I DID get the data from there. Speed was still 400 even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People tend to think of dual channel memory as though it were similar to a RAID-0 setup for hard drives, where the data is striped evenly between two identically-sized hard drives, and speeds are doubled because each drive is only reading/writing half the amount of data, but both are doing it simultaneously.

This is not how dual channel RAM works.

To continue the hard drive analogy, think of it more like a JBOD setup where the combined capacities of two or more differently-sized hard drives are added together to make a single, logical address space.  Individual files are not striped across the disks, but different files may reside on different physical drives.

RAM has always worked that way -- even before RAID or JBOD was a thing with hard drives.  The difference between dual-channel mode and single-channel mode is that **IF** two memory blocks are accessed, **AND** they happen to be on different channels, **THEN** the memory controller can access them both simultaneously.  That's it.

The promise of dual-channel is that it doubles your memory bandwidth.  The reality, however, is that it only improves performance by maybe 5-10%.  Of course, this performance increase is "free" if you're using two memory sticks, so why not?  But if you're shopping for memory and you see a single 8GB stick that's cheaper and spec'd better than two 4GB sticks, you won't be kicking yourself for buying the 8GB one.

---

As for the speed... ya got me there. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I have always understood it that way, and I guess it makes sense that there is no size limitation per se. I guess what confused me is that as long as dual-channel has been a thing that exists, people have recommended matched sticks, (personally never had trouble with even random nonames, but my test base is small) and there are many posts on the 'net that claim non-equal size dual-channel to be impossible.

Comment: @Jostikas; It's a guaranteed compatibility thing. Dual channel operation requires both memory sticks operate at the same speed, but different motherboards have widely different tolerances to mismatched memory. When mismatched pairs are used, some motherboards will just adjust to the lowest speed and work fine, others will drop out of dual channel mode entirely, and some just won't work at all. And with memory, you have latency, timings, and voltage to deal with besides just speed. With all those variables, it just makes sense to buy them in matched pairs.